# Allocated too much memory from VMware to windows MBR disk, how to remove

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, hard-drive

I'm a junior sysadmin and today, I have allocated too much memory to a disk on a windows server 2008 VM through vsphere.

In my srv2008 vm, I saw two disks of 2tb with the same letter (spanned layout)
I needed space so I went in vsphere and raised capacity for one of the two drives, without noticing that in windows, they were mbr.

Now, all the disk that are part of the spanned layout are "Healthy(at risk)", I assume because on one of them I went over 2TB limit for mbr.
It seems like I can't easily remove the memory I allocated on vsphere, and I can't make another disk and add memory to it to increase my disk D:/ space.
I'm running out of space very soon and I'm racing against the clock. This is the main file server, anyone has an idea what I could do?

I tought about just creating another disk, not part of that spanned layout however I don't have enough free space to transfer everything, and I assume a lot of stuff here have hard coded paths to some specific file and moving them else where would break everything

The storage is on a nimble storage array

Comment: Can you not just thin the disks?

Comment: VMware won't let me touch space that was already allocated, and I can not make any operations on the disk as it is in a "at risk" state

Comment: I meant on the ESXi host, convert it to thin-provisioned, then it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to GPT: https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-mbr-to-gpt-on-server.html -- I would caution you to do it on a maintenance window and to have good known backups.  I also am not sure what it will do with a spanned volume.

You could also have done what was done before and add a 3rd leg to the spanned volume.  The whole setup is a little odd for my taste, but at this point it doesn't sound like you have a lot of options for a quick fix.

Comment: I tought about this, but it won't let me add the 3rd leg , I can not do any operation on the disk right now because it is "healthy at risk" unfortunately. I'll reseach a bit about that convert option, try to see what it would do to a spanned volume thanks for the input !

Answer (score -1):

(Apologies if my tone seems a little harsh, and for the generality of the advice (I rarely touch Windows anymore))

The first thing you need to do is be a **professional** sysadmin (isn't that what this site is about?) -- and being professional doesn't necessarily mean having all the technical answers.  It's often more about how you react to problem situations such as this.  Bring this problem to the attention of your more senior admins or management.  They might surprise you with solutions or options you weren't aware of.

Reading your post it sounds as though this hasn't been done and you might be trying to cover up an error. If so, the situation could get **much** worse if any corrective actions you take don't work out as planned.

In regards to your actual problem:

As others have mentioned, work in a maintenance window (planned downtime) and be sure to have good backups.  Fortunately, since you're using VMware, you can take snapshots (NB: *Snapshots are NOT a substitute for backups!*) of your virtual disks.  Thus allowing you to fiddle with the partition tables - or whatever solution you decide to try - *within Windows* (snapshots won't help much if you start altering your disks in ESXi) and revert back if things don't work out as planned.  And don't forget to delete the snapshots when you're finished.

Good Luck!